# How can I get back my full screen back without line

Tags: screen, desktop, apple-silicon

When I rebooted my MBA M1, I see the screen with divider, like a horizontal split screen, with the top pane showing a zoom version of whatever I'm doing in the bigger screen. The line is not movable. Please help!

[image: clueless what to do with this]

Answer (score 2):

You’ve enabled split screen zoom.

Go to System Preferences → Accessibility → Zoom.

- If ‘Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom’ is enabled, use option-command-8 or the shortcut shown on screen if different to toggle zoom off.
- If ‘Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom’ is enabled, hold the modifier key shown and scroll the mouse wheel to zoom out.
- If you still want to use the zoom accessibility feature but don’t want the screen to split when doing so, change the zoom style from ‘split screen’.

Answer (score -1):

Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> should help.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Thank you sooo much to the two of you. I tried unchecking something in the accessibility - zoom  style section and it also worked. Have a nice day!

Comment: @nohillside this disables zoom.